# Hp fortify issue- showing cross site scripting poor validation in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xss, sql-injection, fortify

I am sending data to the client side in json format using rawurlencode method. It is showing cross site scripting poor validation in rawurlencode method in hpfortify.How to remove this issue. Any advice is much appreciated.

my code is -

```
 $json_encoded = rawurlencode($json);
$json_encoded = (preg_match("/[%\da-zA-Z-_]+/",htmlspecialchars($json_encoded,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) ? $json_encoded : 0);
 echo $json_encoded;
```

I get error at **echo $json_encoded** (xss poor validation).

Comment: i have  used  **htmlspecailchars()** and **regular expression** for more validation but the attack thing is still there.

Answer (score 0):

it will always report this issue if you use any non-standard validation function, **you need to write custom rule set (Data Flow) for this function to remove from future scan report** and good thing is, it will remove all issues having this function call.

URLencoding is not correct solution of XSS issues so anyway it is correctly pointing out. (though you're sending this in Json response so xss exploit is actually not possible)

I'm not sure what htmlspecialchars function is doing , please refer [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)to ensure you're using right way of validation.

Comment: The custom rule set that you are talking about.. do i have to write it for the HP fortify or simple function that will validate my data.

Comment: you have to write it for Fortify, please refer HP fortify documentation about writing custom rule set and how to use custom rule set during scan.